# limiting a decimal value to only 2 decimal places in django

Tags: python, mysql, django

This is how I get average marks of a bunch of schools

```
def get_clu_average(self):
    clu_strength = 0
    clu_total = 0
    for school in self.school_set.all():
        clu_strength = clu_strength + school.strength
        clu_total = clu_total + school.get_average() * school.strength
    return clu_total / clu_strength
```

So the value will be a decimal number. When I directly use that in template I am getting a lot of decimal places. How do I restrict the value to only 2 decimal places?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`floatformat`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat) filter in your template:

```
{{ value|floatformat:'2' }}
```

or limit the precision in your view code by either [formatting a string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) for your context or using a [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) instance instead of a float:

```
val = obj.get_clu_average()

val_str = '{.2f}'.format(val)
# OR
from decimal import Decimal as D
val_dec = D(val).quantize(D('0.01'))
```